# evocative vs evocable

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, word-difference

According to [dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/):

> evocable -  capable of being evoked

­

> evocative - tending or serving to evoke

­

To me, their meaning is so similar that I can't see a real difference. For example, are both following phrases correct? Do they mean the same?

`evocative photograph` vs `evocable photograph`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Evocative** = evoking or tending to evoke an especially emotional response ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evocative))

**Evocable** = capable of being evoked ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evocable))

You can think about evocative as a trigger and evocable as being able to respond.

In your example, the photograph can be evocative and the person who looks at it can be evocable. A photograph cannot be evocable, because it's not capable of a response.

Answer (score 2):

X is *evocative* if it *causes* a reaction.

X is *evocable* if it will *respond* to something with a reaction.

Something that is *evocative* requires something *evocable* for there to be anything happening.